# How to get columns names that been updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

Suppose I have a table like this :

```
Table 1: 
    date    account name type status  open_account_date 
    31.12.14  1000    20   40    50      31.12.14
    2.1.15    1000    10   10    50      31.12.14 
    3.1.15    1000     5   15    50      31.12.14
```

and I want to build a summary table like this for the first quarter :

```
account numOfChanges    Changes 
1000        4         (name, type)
```

The first row in table 1 indicats that that the account was opened and somebody enterd for the account some details but the others indicats changes but i want to know which fields has been changed.  Is there any suggestion or an idea how to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartOfQuarter DATE = '1/1/2015'

;WITH cteRcordStateBeforeQuarter AS (
    SELECT
       [date]
       ,account
       ,name
       ,[type]
       ,[status]
       ,open_account_date
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY [date] DESC)
    FROM
       #Table
    WHERE
       [date] < @StartOfQuarter
)

, cteRecordStatesDuringQuarter AS (
    SELECT
       [date]
       ,account
       ,name
       ,[type]
       ,[status]
       ,open_account_date
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY [date] ASC) + 1
       --add 1 because the first row is going to be the last one prior to quarter
       ,LatestChangeRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY [date] DESC)
    FROM
       #Table
    WHERE
       DATEPART(QQ,[date]) = 1
       --change to suite ongoing needs such as quater and YEAR([date]) = ??
)

, cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       [date]
       ,account
       ,name
       ,[type]
       ,[status]
       ,open_account_date
       ,RowNum
       ,LatestChangeRowNum = 0
       ,NumOfChanges = 0
       ,[Changes] = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM
       cteRcordStateBeforeQuarter
    WHERE
       RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       q.[date]
       ,q.account
       ,q.name
       ,q.[type]
       ,q.[status]
       ,q.open_account_date
       ,q.RowNum
       ,LatestChangeRowNum = CAST(q.LatestChangeRowNum AS INT)
       ,NumOfChanges = r.NumOfChanges
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.name,-99999) <> ISNULL(r.name,-99999) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.[type],-99999) <> ISNULL(r.[type],-99999) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.[status],-99999) <> ISNULL(r.[status],-99999) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.open_account_date,'1/1/1900') <> ISNULL(r.open_account_date,'1/1/1900') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ,[Changes] = CAST(ISNULL(r.[Changes],'')
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.name,-99999) <> ISNULL(r.name,-99999) AND r.[Changes] NOT LIKE '%name%' THEN ',name' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.[type],-99999) <> ISNULL(r.[type],-99999) AND r.[Changes] NOT LIKE '%type%' THEN ',type' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.[status],-99999) <> ISNULL(r.[status],-99999) AND r.[Changes] NOT LIKE '%status%' THEN ',status' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.open_account_date,'1/1/1900') <> ISNULL(r.open_account_date,'1/1/1900') AND r.[Changes] NOT LIKE '%open_account_date%' THEN ',open_account_date' ELSE '' END
          AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM
       cteRecordStatesDuringQuarter q
       INNER JOIN cteRecursive r
       ON q.account = r.account
       AND q.RowNum = r.RowNum + 1
)

SELECT
    account
    ,NumOfChanges
    ,[Changes] = REPLACE(IIF(CHARINDEX(',',[Changes]) = 1, RIGHT([Changes],LEN([Changes]) - 1),[Changes]),',',', ')
FROM
    cteRecursive
WHERE
    LatestChangeRowNum = 1
```

If you where using SQL 2012 + it would be a little easier because you could use LAG or LEAD window functions and IIF instead of case.  But a recursive cte works pretty well too.  I assume your recordset will have multiple accounts as well as multiple quarters and there for multiple recordstates prior to the quarter.  Due to this you will need to tweak the date logic slightly but this will give you the gist.

First find the record state prior to the quarter.  Then find all of the changes during the quarter.  Add some row numbers to determine which is the first and which is the last change.  Then use a recursive cte to test for changes.  In the end you just need to format the string the way you want.